# Can't access S3 Hosted Websites via direct path

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, angular-routing

I have a fairly simple Angular website that I've set up to manage a fantasy football draft. It's hosted on S3 as a Single Page Application.

My issue is that I can only access the sub pages if I log in at the top and work through the menu system.

For example if I go to the top site myleague-draft.net then choose 'status' from the dropdown menu the routing works and it redirects to myleague-draft.net/status. However if I attempt to go to the path directly from the address bar - i.e. type in myleague-draft.net/status it gives me a 404.

Also, when I run the project locally on my dev machine and type in localhost:4200/status it works.

So my question is... Is there something to configure in S3 to have it route correctly? If not, is there something specific in Angular

I'm declaring the routes in the app.module.ts like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'setup', component: SetupComponent },
      { path: 'auction', component: AuctionComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'status', component: DraftSelectionsComponent },
      { path: 'stats', component: TeamStatisticsComponent },
      { path: 'summary', component: OwnerSummaryComponent },
      { path: 'budgets', component: BudgetsComponent },
      { path: 'owner', component: OwnerDraftedPlayersComponent },
      { path: 'watchlist', component: WatchlistComponent },
      { path: 'statistics', component: StatisticsComponent }
    ]
```

I've also tried loading the routes directly in the AppRoutingModule directly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the 'correct' way to solve this problem, but I was able to make it work by creating a folder for each path and copying the index.html file to it.

In the aws cli I just did this:

```
aws s3 cp index.html s3://myleague-draft.net/setup/
aws s3 cp index.html s3://myleague-draft.net/auction/
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the website is an SPA, then we need to make sure all requests to the server (S3 in this case) return something even if no file exists. This is becuase SPAs like React (with React Router) need the index.html page for every requests, then things like "not found" pages are handled in the front-end.
Set the default error page for 404 Not found code to /index.html

```
HTTP Error Code: 404
TTL: 0
Custom Error Response: Yes
Response Page Path: /index.html
HTTP Response Code: 200
```